# Gulp: Sass task is not defined after saving scss

Tags: sass, gulp, underscores-wp

I've been having a few issues trying to get Gulp working properly for a local Understrap Wordpress theme project I've been working on. I finally got it to a point where it will Start the "Watch" and "Default" processes, but then when I save my `.scss` files, I'm getting an error that says `Error: task "sass" is not defined.`

After that error, there are a number of other flags that mention `sequencify`, `orchestrator`, `gulp-sequence`, and `thunks`.

Below, I've included my gulpfile.js and the whole error code I'm receiving in terminal. I've been Googling for hours, and I can't seem to find a solution that fits into this scenario. I've tried rebuilding npm and uninstalling/reinstalling all my nodes, to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

**My gulpfile.js**
This is pretty much the standard file that comes with the Understrap theme.

```
// Defining requirements  
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );  
var plumber = require( 'gulp-plumber' );  
var sass = require( 'gulp-sass' );  
var watch = require( 'gulp-watch' );  
var rename = require( 'gulp-rename' );  
var concat = require( 'gulp-concat' );  
var uglify = require( 'gulp-uglify' );  
var imagemin = require( 'gulp-imagemin' );  
var ignore = require( 'gulp-ignore' );  
var rimraf = require( 'gulp-rimraf' );  
var sourcemaps = require( 'gulp-sourcemaps' );  
var browserSync = require( 'browser-sync' ).create();  
var del = require( 'del' );  
var cleanCSS = require( 'gulp-clean-css' );  
var gulpSequence = require( 'gulp-sequence' );  
var replace = require( 'gulp-replace' );  
var autoprefixer = require( 'gulp-autoprefixer' );  

// Configuration file to keep your code DRY  
var cfg = require( './gulpconfig.json' );  
var paths = cfg.paths;  

// Load Gulp plugins from package dependencies  
// var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();  

// Run:  
// gulp sass  
// Compiles SCSS files in CSS  
gulp.task( 'sass', function() {  
    var stream = gulp.src( paths.sass + '/*.scss' )  
       .pipe( plumber( {  
            errorHandler: function( err ) {  
                console.log( err );  
                this.emit( 'end' );  
            }  
        } ) )  
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))  
        .pipe( sass( { errLogToConsole: true } ) )  
        .pipe( autoprefixer( 'last 2 versions' ) )  
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(undefined, { sourceRoot: null }))  
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.css ) )  
    return stream;  
});  

// Run:  
// gulp watch  
// Starts watcher. Watcher runs gulp sass task on changes  
gulp.task( 'watch', function() {  
    gulp.watch( paths.sass + '/**/*.scss', ['styles'] );  
    gulp.watch( [paths.dev + '/js/**/*.js', 'js/**/*.js', '!js/theme.js', 
  '!js/theme.min.js'], ['scripts'] );  

    //Inside the watch task.  
    gulp.watch( paths.imgsrc + '/**', ['imagemin-watch'] );  
});  

/**  
 * Ensures the 'imagemin' task is complete before reloading browsers  
 * @verbose  
 */  
gulp.task( 'imagemin-watch', ['imagemin'], function( ) {  
  browserSync.reload();  
});  

// Run:  
// gulp imagemin  
// Running image optimizing task  
gulp.task( 'imagemin', function() {  
    gulp.src( paths.imgsrc + '/**' )  
    .pipe( imagemin() )  
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.img ) );  
});  

// Run:  
// gulp cssnano  
// Minifies CSS files  
gulp.task( 'cssnano', function() {  
  return gulp.src( paths.css + '/theme.css' )  
    .pipe( sourcemaps.init( { loadMaps: true } ) )  
    .pipe( plumber( {  
            errorHandler: function( err ) {  
                console.log( err );  
                this.emit( 'end' );  
            }  
        } ) )  
    .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )  
    .pipe( cssnano( { discardComments: { removeAll: true } } ) )  
    .pipe( sourcemaps.write( './' ) )  
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.css ) );  
});  

gulp.task( 'minifycss', function() {  
  return gulp.src( paths.css + '/theme.css' )  
  .pipe( sourcemaps.init( { loadMaps: true } ) )  
    .pipe( cleanCSS( { compatibility: '*' } ) )  
    .pipe( plumber( {  
            errorHandler: function( err ) {  
                console.log( err ) ;  
                this.emit( 'end' );  
            }  
        } ) )  
    .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )  
     .pipe( sourcemaps.write( './' ) )  
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.css ) );  
});  

gulp.task( 'cleancss', function() {  
  return gulp.src( paths.css + '/*.min.css', { read: false } ) // Much faster  
    .pipe( ignore( 'theme.css' ) )  
    .pipe( rimraf() );  
});  

gulp.task( 'styles', function( callback ) {  
    gulpSequence( 'sass', 'minifycss' )( callback );  
} );  

// Run:  
// gulp browser-sync  
// Starts browser-sync task for starting the server.  
gulp.task( 'browser-sync', function() {  
    browserSync.init( cfg.browserSyncWatchFiles, cfg.browserSyncOptions );  
} );  

// Run:  
// gulp watch-bs  
// Starts watcher with browser-sync. Browser-sync reloads page automatically on your browser  
gulp.task( 'watch-bs', ['browser-sync', 'watch', 'scripts'], function() {
} );  

// Run:  
// gulp scripts.  
// Uglifies and concat all JS files into one  
gulp.task( 'scripts', function() {  
    var scripts = [  

        // Start - All BS4 stuff  
        paths.dev + '/js/bootstrap4/bootstrap.bundle.js',  

        // End - All BS4 stuff  

        paths.dev + '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js',  

        // Adding currently empty javascript file to add on for your own themes´ customizations  
        // Please add any customizations to this .js file only!  
        paths.dev + '/js/custom-javascript.js'  
    ];  
  gulp.src( scripts )  
    .pipe( concat( 'theme.min.js' ) )  
    .pipe( uglify() )  
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.js ) );  

  gulp.src( scripts )  
    .pipe( concat( 'theme.js' ) )  
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.js ) );  
});  

// Deleting any file inside the /src folder  
gulp.task( 'clean-source', function() {  
  return del( ['src/**/*'] );  
});  

// Run:  
// gulp copy-assets.  
// Copy all needed dependency assets files from bower_component assets to themes /js, /scss and /fonts folder. Run this task after bower install or bower update  

////////////////// All Bootstrap SASS  Assets /////////////////////////  
gulp.task( 'copy-assets', function() {  

////////////////// All Bootstrap 4 Assets /////////////////////////  
// Copy all JS files  
    var stream = gulp.src( paths.node + 'bootstrap/dist/js/**/*.js' )  
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dev + '/js/bootstrap4' ) );  

// Copy all Bootstrap SCSS files  
    gulp.src( paths.node + 'bootstrap/scss/**/*.scss' )  
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dev + '/sass/bootstrap4' ) );  

////////////////// End Bootstrap 4 Assets /////////////////////////  

// Copy all Font Awesome Fonts  
    gulp.src( paths.node + 'font-awesome/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,woff2,eot,svg}' )  
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './fonts' ) );  

// Copy all Font Awesome SCSS files  
    gulp.src( paths.node + 'font-awesome/scss/*.scss' )  
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dev + '/sass/fontawesome' ) );  

// _s SCSS files  
    gulp.src( paths.node + 'undescores-for-npm/sass/media/*.scss' )  
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dev + '/sass/underscores' ) );  

// _s JS files into /src/js  
    gulp.src( paths.node + 'undescores-for-npm/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js' )  
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dev + '/js' ) );  
});  

// Deleting the files distributed by the copy-assets task  
gulp.task( 'clean-vendor-assets', function() {  
  return del( [paths.dev + '/js/bootstrap4/**', paths.dev + '/sass/bootstrap4/**', './fonts/*wesome*.{ttf,woff,woff2,eot,svg}', paths.dev + '/sass/fontawesome/**', paths.dev + '/sass/underscores/**', paths.dev + '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', paths.js + '/**/skip-link-focus-fix.js', paths.js + '/**/popper.min.js', paths.js + '/**/popper.js', ( paths.vendor !== ''?( paths.js + paths.vendor + '/**' ):'' )] );  
});  

// Run  
// gulp dist  
// Copies the files to the /dist folder for distribution as simple theme
gulp.task( 'dist', ['clean-dist'], function() {  
  return gulp.src( ['**/*', '!' + paths.bower, '!' + paths.bower + '/**', '!' + paths.node, '!' + paths.node + '/**', '!' + paths.dev, '!' + paths.dev + '/**', '!' + paths.dist, '!' + paths.dist + '/**', '!' + paths.distprod, '!' + paths.distprod + '/**', '!' + paths.sass, '!' + paths.sass + '/**', '!readme.txt', '!readme.md', '!package.json', '!package-lock.json', '!gulpfile.js', '!gulpconfig.json', '!CHANGELOG.md', '!.travis.yml', '!jshintignore',  '!codesniffer.ruleset.xml',  '*'], { 'buffer': true } )  
  .pipe( replace( '/js/jquery.slim.min.js', '/js' + paths.vendor + '/jquery.slim.min.js', { 'skipBinary': true } ) )  
  .pipe( replace( '/js/popper.min.js', '/js' + paths.vendor + '/popper.min.js', { 'skipBinary': true } ) )  
  .pipe( replace( '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', '/js' + paths.vendor + '/skip-link-focus-fix.js', { 'skipBinary': true } ) )  
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dist ) );  
});  

// Deleting any file inside the /dist folder  
gulp.task( 'clean-dist', function() {  
  return del( [paths.dist + '/**'] );  
});  

// Run  
// gulp dist-product  
// Copies the files to the /dist-prod folder for distribution as theme with all assets  
gulp.task( 'dist-product', ['clean-dist-product'], function() {  
  return gulp.src( ['**/*', '!' + paths.bower, '!' + paths.bower + '/**', '!' + paths.node, '!' + paths.node + '/**', '!' + paths.dist, '!' + paths.dist +'/**', '!' + paths.distprod, '!' + paths.distprod + '/**', '*'] )  
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.distprod ) );  
} );  

// Deleting any file inside the /dist-product folder  
gulp.task( 'clean-dist-product', function() {  
  return del( [paths.distprod + '/**'] );  
} );  

// Run:  
// gulp  
// Starts watcher (default task)  
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

**My terminal process and error message after saving my `.scss` files**

```
arobinson$ gulp  
[15:27:23] Using gulpfile /understrap-child/gulpfile.js  
[15:27:23] Starting 'watch'...  
[15:27:23] Finished 'watch' after 12 ms  
[15:27:23] Starting 'default'...  
[15:27:23] Finished 'default' after 21 μs  
[15:27:35] Starting 'styles'...  
[15:27:35] 'styles' errored after 171 ms  
[15:27:35] Error: task "sass" is not defined  
    at Gulp.sequence (/Users/arobinson/node_modules/sequencify/index.js:14:9)  
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/arobinson/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:115:9)  
    at /Users/arobinson/node_modules/gulp-sequence/index.js:66:12  
    at apply (/Users/arobinson/node_modules/thunks/index.js:354:38)  
    at tryRun (/Users/arobinson/node_modules/thunks/index.js:224:19)  
    at runThunk (/Users/arobinson/node_modules/thunks/index.js:217:15)  
    at /Users/arobinson/node_modules/thunks/index.js:314:49  
    at apply (/Users/arobinson/node_modules/thunks/index.js:354:38)  
    at tryRun (/Users/arobinson/node_modules/thunks/index.js:224:19)  
    at runThunk (/Users/arobinson/node_modules/thunks/index.js:217:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [gulp-sequence docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sequence#gulpsequenceusegulp):

> **gulpSequence.use(gulp)**
>
> return a new gulpSequence function with the gulp. If you have some
>   errors such as "`task xxx is not defined`", this will resolve it.
>
> ```
> var gulpSequence = require('gulp-sequence').use(gulp)
> ```

So change to

```
var gulpSequence = require('gulp-sequence').use(gulp)
```

and see if that helps.